# Extract first element from string

Tags: r

I want to pull first element from square brackets of c([a,b],[c,d]). See the example below -

```
x <- "[\"Multi & Flexi-Cap\", \"Multi & Flexi Cap Fund\"], [\"Large-Cap\", \"Large Cap Fund\"], [\"Large & Mid-Cap\", \"Large & Mid Cap Fund\"], [\"Mid-Cap\", \"Mid Cap Fund\"], [\"Small-Cap\", \"Small Cap Fund\"], [\"ELSS\", \"ELSS (Tax Savings)\"], [\"Dividend Yield\", \"Dividend Yield\"], [\"Equity - Sectoral\", \"Sectoral/Thematic\"], [\"Contra\", \"Contra Fund\"], [\"Focused Fund\", \"Focused Fund\"], [\"Value\", \"Value Fund\"], [\"RGESS\", \"RGESS\"], [\"Equity - Other\", \"Equity - Other\"]"
```

Desired Output of first 3 brackets [ ]

```
c("Multi & Flexi-Cap", "Large-Cap", "Large & Mid-Cap")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `stringr` you could try:

```r
x <- "[\"Multi & Flexi-Cap\", \"Multi & Flexi Cap Fund\"], [\"Large-Cap\", \"Large Cap Fund\"], [\"Large & Mid-Cap\", \"Large & Mid Cap Fund\"], [\"Mid-Cap\", \"Mid Cap Fund\"], [\"Small-Cap\", \"Small Cap Fund\"], [\"ELSS\", \"ELSS (Tax Savings)\"], [\"Dividend Yield\", \"Dividend Yield\"], [\"Equity - Sectoral\", \"Sectoral/Thematic\"], [\"Contra\", \"Contra Fund\"], [\"Focused Fund\", \"Focused Fund\"], [\"Value\", \"Value Fund\"], [\"RGESS\", \"RGESS\"], [\"Equity - Other\", \"Equity - Other\"]"

library(stringr)

unlist(str_extract_all(x, "(?<=\\[\\\\?[:punct:])[A-z &-]*(?=\\\\?)"))
#>  [1] "Multi & Flexi-Cap" "Large-Cap"         "Large & Mid-Cap"  
#>  [4] "Mid-Cap"           "Small-Cap"         "ELSS"             
#>  [7] "Dividend Yield"    "Equity - Sectoral" "Contra"           
#> [10] "Focused Fund"      "Value"             "RGESS"            
#> [13] "Equity - Other"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression:

```r
gsub("\\[([^,]+).*", "\\1", x)
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `reticulate`

```
library(reticulate)
py_run_string(paste0('x = ', x))
sapply(py$x, `[`, 1)
```

-output

```
[1] "Multi & Flexi-Cap" "Large-Cap"         "Large & Mid-Cap"   "Mid-Cap"           "Small-Cap"         "ELSS"              "Dividend Yield"   
 [8] "Equity - Sectoral" "Contra"            "Focused Fund"      "Value"             "RGESS"             "Equity - Other"
```

#### data

```
x <- "[\"Multi & Flexi-Cap\", \"Multi & Flexi Cap Fund\"], [\"Large-Cap\", \"Large Cap Fund\"], [\"Large & Mid-Cap\", \"Large & Mid Cap Fund\"], [\"Mid-Cap\", \"Mid Cap Fund\"], [\"Small-Cap\", \"Small Cap Fund\"], [\"ELSS\", \"ELSS (Tax Savings)\"], [\"Dividend Yield\", \"Dividend Yield\"], [\"Equity - Sectoral\", \"Sectoral/Thematic\"], [\"Contra\", \"Contra Fund\"], [\"Focused Fund\", \"Focused Fund\"], [\"Value\", \"Value Fund\"], [\"RGESS\", \"RGESS\"], [\"Equity - Other\", \"Equity - Other\"]"
```